# rsync command option for file attribute

Tags: rsync

I am using rsync command to copy over data from one location to another.
However, the command option description for rsync -a option says that the -a command also preserves file permissions and user information.

**Question**
Does this mean, if I have used -a option to copy over data from my Work laptop to say an external hard drive, I can't access these files because I may not have the user permissions (say my local laptop user is not the same as the one who created it)

Reference: https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync

Answer (score 1):

As an administrator of your local laptop, you will be able to modify file permissions & user information on your external hard drive when you need to.

File permissions & user information is only relevant on a running system. Once you unplug a hard drive from a running system, or copy a file out of that system, the file permission & user information is only there for your information, they cannot stop you from doing anything.

That's why hardware security is the most important aspect of data security.

That's my understanding.